# Qt How to set background color for QTabBar content?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have found the common way to style a QTabBar content background with a stylesheet is like:

```
QTabWidget QWidget {
    background-color: green;
}
```

The result would be like the desired one:

[image]

But problem is that QWidget also applies the background color to all objects inside the QTabWidget, that is, QToolButtons, QPushButtons, QFrames, etc...
It's a pain in the ass for me because I need to apply once again all the background to my elements that are placed inside the tabs like:

```
QTabWidget QPushButton,
QTabWidget QToolButton {
     background-color: red;
}
... (and so on)
```

I don't think it is a smart solution because I also have nested QTabWidgets so it turns crazy because I need to "reset" all backgrounds element each time I nest a new QTabWidget inside the previous one...

I would be perfect to have access to the direct element or subelement "background"...
Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
QTabWidget QStackedWidget > QWidget  
{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the better solution I found:

```
QTabWidget::pane {
    background-color: red;
}
```